# How do I get a complete animation loop in one keystroke?

Tags: libgdx

What do I need to fix so that a single keystroke plays one full animation loop?

Creating animation object:

```
jojoStandSummonTextureAtlasRight = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("jojo/stand_summon/right/jojo_stand_summon.atlas"));
jojoStandSummonAnimationRight = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1 / 3f, jojoStandSummonTextureAtlasRight.getRegions());
```

Rendering animations:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(E) && lastKeyInput == RIGHT){
            sb.draw(jojo.jojoStandSummonAnimationRight.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, false), jojo.getPosition().x, jojo.getPosition().y);
            lastKeyInput = RIGHT;
        }
```

Comment: You'll have to set a boolean or change a state variable that tracks which animation should be playing for the particular game object and draw it based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Animation class provided by LibGDX includes an **.isAnimationFinished()** function. This will return a boolean indicating when the animation has finished playing.

In your case, I assume you're updating your elapsedTime variable in your update() function. So you can do something like:

```
if(!jojoStandSummonAnimationRight.isAnimationFinished()) {
    elapsed_time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
} else {
    // animation is finished
}
```